# Difference between & and && in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, bitwise-operators, logical-operators, operands

I am trying to figure out the difference between & and && in Scala. I got this after searching

> & <-- verifies both operands
>
> && <-- stops evaluating if the first operand evaluates to false since the result will be false

Can somebody explain the same with example as am not clear, what verifying both operands means here. Are we talking about just Booleans?

Comment: I'd think bitwise operators would only work on integers… Other than that it's just the [same as in any other language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35301/1048572)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688343/why-doesnt-the-bitwise-operator-short-circuit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both are logical AND operators in Scala. The first form, `&`, will evaluate both operands values, for example:

```
val first = false
val second = true

if (first & second) println("Hello!")
```

Will evaluate both `first` and `second` before exiting the if condition, although we know that once a `false` appears in a logical AND, that entire expression will already yield false.

This is what `&&` is for, and what it does is short-circuit the evaluation, meaning you only ever evaluate `first`s value and then exit the conditional.

You can use bitwise AND (`&`) to perform bitwise operations on integers, which is similar to most programming languages.

Comment: If the first value turns out to be true in case of &&, then?

Comment: @NeoWelkin Then `second` will also be evaluated to determine the result of the expression, because it now depends on it.